# How To Add A Similar Products View To A Commerce Product Display?

Tags: views, commerce

On the Commerce Kickstart Product Display, I want to add a View which shows related products. I think I can figure out how to create the related products view, but I can't figure out how to add the view to the Product Display node.

Is this done by creating a TPL for the Product Type?

I tried to create a view and display that view block on the content type and nothing happens.

Suggestions?

Comment: Block and contextual filters? Or maybe [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield)?

Comment: Thanks. How does one attach a block to a form?

Comment: Not to a form, but to specific URLs. Create a block and see it's settings, "show only on", sth like that.